# Get random record using like query in postgres

Tags: postgresql, random, sql-order-by, sql-like, alphabetical-sort

I am having an table with email_address as a primary key and there is no id column in the table.

So whenever I hit the query like

```
select email_address from data  where email_address like '%@gmail.com' limit 10
```

it gives result alphabetically means all the email-id starting with a (if its present).

But I don't want like alphabetic order, I want result like

```
email_address
___________________
a@gmail.com
k@gmail.com
d@gmail.com
b@gmail.com
```

Pick randomly email address which ends with gmail.com, not by inserted order or not by alphabetic order.

NOTE : I have like 1000's of result starting with each alphabet when I pick just 100 then I want not only all the result starting with 'a'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you order them randomly and then pick the first top 10 results I guess that could work. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT email_address FROM data
WHERE email_address LIKE '%@gmail.com'
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Sorry, Its working.. Its my mistake when I checked my db it has all the email starting with 'a'. Now its working

Comment: I would be happy if you upvote the right answer, which you downvoted :)